# Finding duplicate emails from MailItem (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook)?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, office-interop

I am working on a little loader program to read through multiple users emails (each user will run it themselves) and load error emails they got from multiple different mailing lists into a DB so we can start analysing the errors.

Each user should have a LOT of the same emails, so I am looking for a way to possitively identify two emails are the same.  It does not appear there is a unique ID that can be used.  The creation date is often off by a few fractions of a second.  Is there any way to determine if an email is already been captures?

Comment: It all depends on your definition of "duplicate emails". Are they the same if the subject and body minus white space match? Do they match if sent time is off by more than a minute? Are they duplicate if recipients are the same?

Comment: The emails are auto-generated by applications that are having some type of error.  The errors might be serious, they might not be.  It is completely possible for one application to send the EXACT same email, same subject, same body all within a second.  Mind you, they should not do that, but the nature of this environment, that is possible.